# FIle format of eclipse workspace files

Tags: eclipse, file, format, workspace

Is there a (good) documentation about the format of the eclipse workspace files (.location, x.tree, ...)?

I need this to programatically create a workspace for automated builds. Unfortunately I have to do this job from a .NET program, so I can't use any Eclipse classes to do this! (We manage our Linux C++ projects using Eclipse + CDT).

Comment: This doesn't really makes sense, explain the other tools you use, your environment, maybe there's another solution?

Comment: Have you tried to create a make file a build the c++/linux project from the command line? And then use that from your other build engine (msbuild). You do not need Eclipse to build your project (unless you're using JNI and bridging to Java to create an Eclipse Plug-in, doubtful).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not exactly a precise answer, but I just would point out the following sources for your question:

- [Eclipse Wiki](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Workspace),
- [Eclipse Workspace Team Blog](http://polishineclipse.blogspot.com/)
- Eclipse [**platform mailing list**](http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.platform/maillist.html)

May between those three links you will find the actual documentation for workspace structure (if you do, post an answer here ;) )

Answer (score 1):

This will not be a helpful answer.

If you possibly can, I would try and coax Eclipse to generate the workspace for you. Otherwise you will be delving in a lot of undocumented internal APIs, and trying to re-implement the filessytem, which is in-effect another internal APIs.

Eclipse makes it clear that you are on your own when using internal APIs, and are careful to say that these may break at any time (e.g. a very minor point release).

**Edit**: you may also find help looking at suggestions for this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/305787/how-can-i-build-an-eclipse-plugin-outside-of-eclipse). And [buckminster](http://www.eclipse.org/buckminster/), which you may find useful for other reasons too.

Comment: I don't think you'll need to learn any Java, just enough about it to spin up eclipse to do it for you. See edits.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how complex your build system is, it may be simpler to use a dedicated build system such as Apache Ant or Nant.  There is a .NET library for Ant at: http://ant.apache.org/antlibs/dotnet/ and there may be other build systems as well.

Answer (score -1):

This is a pretty good solution:

http://eclipseone.wordpress.com/2010/01/25/checkout-multiple-projects-automatically-into-your-eclipse-workspace/

Comment: It would be nice if you summed up the content of the website instead of just providing the link.